# jquery draggable non list item to sortable list

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

This seems to be trivial but here I am anyway. The code below is a simple drag a drop with a sortable list. What i would like to do is do some work on the dropped in element. In this example the dropped in item is a div. The work I would like to do is create a new list item with the div inside.

Any help?

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".sortable").sortable();
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
    }); 
}
</script>
<div class="draggable">DRAG ME</div>
<ul class="sortable">
    <li>ITEM 1</li>
    <li>ITEM 2</li>
    <li>ITEM 3</li>
    <li>ITEM 4</li>
</ul>
```

here is some stuff I also tried

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        receive: function(event, ui) { 
            ui.item = $("<li></li>").append(ui.item);
        }
    });

    $('.sortable').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui){
            ui.draggable = $("<li></li>").append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the work you would like to do to the element? When it's dropped into the sort, you want it to go in as an `<li>`? Not sure I'm understanding.

Comment: modified op and added some some samples to make a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `stop` event on the Sortable:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
   stop: function(event, ui)
   {
      if (ui.item.is('div.draggable'))
         ui.item.replaceWith($('<li>' + ui.item.text() + '</li>'));
   }
});
```

Reference for learning: [stop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop) event

A similar question that helped with finding the answer: [Using jQuery UI drag-and-drop: changing the dragged element on drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162487/using-jquery-ui-drag-and-drop-changing-the-dragged-element-on-drop)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
li {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid #cfc;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
<title>Drag and Sort</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".sortable").sortable();
   $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        stop: function(event, ui){
            var content = $(this).html();
            $('ul.sortable>div').replaceWith($('<li />').html(content));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<body id="container">
    <div class="draggable">DRAG ME</div>
    <ul class="sortable">
        <li>ITEM 1</li>
        <li>ITEM 2</li>
        <li>ITEM 3</li>
        <li>ITEM 4</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to turn the `div` into an `li` before it is inserted into `ul.sortable`.

Comment: I was seeing the syntax errors in the top `<script>` block and thinking that was the problem. " I would like to do some work on the element before it becomes part of the list." is vague.